# List of Figures and tables not in contents

Tags: pdftex

I am using the following commands for list of Figures and Tables. I could find both inside of my theory part. But they are not displayed in the contents Part.
* Edited

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,\myPageLayout]{book} 
\begin{document} \fontmatter 
\usepackage[acronym,footnote,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\mainmatter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
{\parskip=0mm \tableofcontents}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Figures}]
\listoffigures
\newpage
\glsaddall
\printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Tables}]
\listoftables
% then comes all chapters content (I have 5 chapters)
\appendix
{
\small
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter{Index}}
\printindex
}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciable

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `\glsaddall` etc? They have nothing to do with `\listoffigures` etc.

Comment: @user8162: Now, that you use the **class** book:  Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @user8162: Did you try your minimal document above? I think it misses at least `\usepackage{glossaries}`

Comment: @user8162: What about `\myPagestyle`???

Comment: '\fancypagestyle{mine}{\pagestyle{\myPageLayout mine}}'

Comment: @user8162 Please check that the code you are giving us compiles before uploading it. We should be able to copy your code, paste it into a blank document and compile it. [Exception: if you are asking specifically why you get an error when you try to compile. Obviously, in that case, your code should give us that error when we try to compile it.]

Comment: I don't understand your code. Why is `\myPagestyle` being passed to the `book` class as an option if you define it later after, presumably, loading `fancyhdr`. And does this have anything to do with the problem you're asking about? Also, what is the connection between the use of glossaries and the lists of figures and tables supposed to be?

Comment: `\usepackage` needs to come *before* `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @cfr to make sure, \usepackage is before \begin{document} only. Regarding \mypagestyle- this was the template given to me. So if this not correct. Could you please correct me.

Comment: In your example, `\usepackage` is *after* `\begin{document}`. I can't tell you how to do it because I don't understand what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: I actually did this from this linjk https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Lists_of_tables_and_figures. My requirement is that, I need to include list of figures and tables in my latex and they also should appear in my content page. So for this Do u suggest me someother method ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple example based on the template you linked to, but adapted for the `book` class and adjusted in light of karlkoeller's comment. This is actually how I would usually tend to do this, as I don't usually use things like contents in articles.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

  \thispagestyle{empty}

  \tableofcontents

  \cleardoublepage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}\listoffigures

  \cleardoublepage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename}\listoftables

  \newpage

  \pagenumbering{arabic}

  \chapter{First chapter}

  This section contains a figure (\ref{fig:first}).
  \begin{figure}
    first figure
    \caption{first}\label{fig:first}
  \end{figure}

  \chapter{Second chapter}

  This section contains figure \ref{fig:second} and table \ref{tab:first}.
  \begin{figure}
    second figure
    \caption{second}\label{fig:second}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{table}
    first table
    \caption{first}\label{tab:first}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: lof and lot in toc]

Comment: @cfr..Thank u so much.. This answer works perfectly....

Comment: With this solution, the page number is not correct if one the lists spans over more than one page...

Comment: @karlkoeller You're right, of course. I think because the template used `article`, I was assuming the lists would be relatively short since the assumption seems to be that they'll all fit on one page. I've switched the class to `book` which is what the OP seems to possibly be using. (This is how I tend to do this myself, but I don't tend to have ToCs in articles.) Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear to me how you are generating your "List of Tables" and "List of Figures"...

If you are generating them through `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures`, it suffices to load the package `tocbibind` with the option `nottoc` (to avoid having the ToC itself in the ToC):

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

If, instead, you are using the `glossaries` package to generate them, you have to use the option `toc` to add your glossaries in the ToC.

That is, load `glossaries` as

```
\usepackage[acronym,footnote,nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}
```

Sorry for not providing a MWE, but yours is uncompilable...

Answer (score 1):

Try to start from following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[acronym,footnote,nonumberlist]{glossaries}    
    \begin{document} 
\frontmatter   
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
   \listoftables
\mainmatter
    \chapter{first chapter}
    \section{first section}
        \begin{figure}[h]
some figure
        \caption{Caption of the first figure}
        \end{figure}
    \section{second section}
       \begin{table}[h]
      \caption{first table}
content of table
        \end{table}    
\end{document}
```

It gives contents, list of figures and list of tables. You now can added your formatting and look, when the list of figures and tables disappear. And read given comments carefully, they are very valued.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But even now, I am getting list of tables and figures inside my PDF, but NOT in contents.

Comment: I,m sorry, but this request in your post was not clear to me. Meanwhile cfr gives you hint how to do this.