# Table of contents doesn't show list of acronyms

Tags: table-of-contents, acronyms

I'm having issues making my table of contents show the location of the list of acronyms.

I followed [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220059/list-of-figures-and-tables-not-in-contents) and managed to make it work for the List of Figures and List of Tables, with the following:

```
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename}\listoftables
```

But I don't know how do add a contents line for my list of acronyms. Currently I only have these at the end of my document, which renders the acronyms:

```
\printnoidxglossary % default: type=main
\printnoidxglossary[type=acronym]
\printnoidxglossary[type=symbols]
```

Comment: Have you tried `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Acronyms}`?  The `\listof...` commands are separate commands in your example.

Comment: that worked perfectly! I added it as the answer. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that simply adding the following, immediately before the acronyms section, works:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Acronyms}
```

Thanks to @Teepeemm in the comments for this answer.